# How to draw the 3d planes?

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry

The equations for planes I have are $x=0$, $x=1$, $y=0$, $y=1$, $z=0$, $z=1$ but these to me look like equation of the lines. Apparently, they form a cube in 3d coordinates. Is it possible use some online graphing calculator to visualize what it is?

[image]

Comment: Wolframalpha is probably what you want.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the plane $x=0$ is the set of all points $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x=0\}$. It's just the $yz$-plane in this case. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: So, when $x = 0$, then $y = 1$ and $z = 1$? I also thought the equation of plane to be $ax + by + cz = d$.

Comment: $x = 0$ is a shorthand for a plane. In the same way that $x = 0$ is shorthand for a line in two-dimensions. Although you tend to describe lines in $y = mx + b$ or $ax + by = c$, there is no way to describe the lines or planes $x = 0$ in those equations.

Comment: @user963241 Actually $x=0$ defines the entire $yz$ plane. Basically only the $x$ value is fixed at zero, while  $y$ and $z$ and all possible values for these are included. So the general point defined by $x=0$ is $(0,y,z)$. $x=1$ is the plane parallel to this one obtained by translating the $yz$ plane one unit in the positive $x$ direction. And all these planes intersect to give the cube as their interior.

Answer (score 1):

All six are equations of planes. For example, $x=0$ means that while $x$ is zero, $y$ and $z$ are free to be anything. It's the set of points given by $(0,y,z)$ where $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.

I went ahead and plotted it using Mathematica. The two graphics give us two looks: the second picture has been zoomed in (look at the axes) to get a better look at the unit cube created by the intersection of the six planes.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, x == 1, y == 0, y == 1, z == 0,z == 1}, {x, -.1, 1.1}, {y, -.1, 1.1}, {z, -.1, 1.1}]
```

[image: unit cube created by intersection of six planes]

For the future, you can invest in software like Mathematica or MATLAB, or try free resources like [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com) or [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) for graphing. Not sure if either can handle contour plots in 3D, but I figure there's some level of support.